# Pyo3 library using sdl2

Tags: python, rust, sdl-2, pyo3

I was gonna create a Pyo3 library which implements some RL environments. I had been using Pyo3 for other tasks. I was gonna use also SDL2 rendering, however it gives me an error.

```
#[pyclass]
pub struct FirstEnv {
   pos: f32,
   renderer: Renderer,
}

pub struct Renderer {
    canvas: sdl2::render::WindowCanvas,
}
```

The error:
`Rc<RendererContext<WindowContext>>` cannot be sent between threads safely

Is there a fix for this ? Or this kind of a combo will not work?

It shows me that within `FirstEnv`, the trait `Send` is not implemented for `Rc<RendererContext<WindowContext>>`. As I am new in rust tried googling and it says that it is not thread safe. However, I am not sure what should I do.

Comment: Try `Rc`s atomically counted cousin [`Arc`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Arc.html)

Comment: @cafce25 The `Rc` is inside [`WindowCanvas`](https://docs.rs/sdl2/0.35.2/src/sdl2/render.rs.html#346-350). So it's not like Edvards can just switch that. (I don't think wrapping the `WindowCanvas` into an `Arc<Mutex<T>>` would help either, because `Mutex` won't be `Send` if `T` isn't. But I might be wrong.)

Comment: Yes, I tried wrapping it in `Arc<Mutex<T>>` it still gave me the same error.

Comment: Ultimately, you may have to use a bigger hammer: Have a rendering thread that has exclusive access to the `WindowCanvas`, and pass messages to that thread (through `crossbeam` or similar).